# Unable to give $_Session value in captcha file

Tags: php, ajax, html, session

I am unable to give `$_Session` value in a captcha file.

Here is my captcha file:

```
<?php
session_name('U');
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly',true);
$string='';
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){$string.=chr(rand(97,122));}
$_SESSION['img']=$string;
$fDir='includes/images/captcha_backgrounds/fonts/';
$fs=glob($fDir.'*.{ttf,otf}',GLOB_BRACE);
$RF=$fs[array_rand($fs)];
$imagesDir='includes/images/captcha_backgrounds/';
$images=glob($imagesDir.'*.{jpg}',GLOB_BRACE);
$randomImage=$images[array_rand($images)];
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg($randomImage);
$color=imagecolorallocate($image,rand(000,255),rand(000,255),rand(000,255));
imagettftext($image,40,0,20,70,$color,$RF,$_SESSION['img']);
header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($image);
?>
```

Here is how I `src` the captcha:

```
<img src="captcha.php"/>
```

And when I submit the form to another page it returns the error:

> $_SESSION("img") is undefined

I am getting the captcha image fine but the session is not working please help.

Also, I am submitting the form using AJAX.

It all works well except the session.

Comment: is `session_start();` inside **all** files using sessions?

Comment: Yes it is in all the files @Fred-ii-

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: This `header("Content-type:image/png");` and you're using `jpg`. Try `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- it worked thanks a lot can you post it as a answer so that I can accept it

Comment: You're welcome Abhishek. It has been done, *cheers*. Glad to know it worked out well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Thanks @Fred-ii- it worked thanks a lot can you post it as a answer so that I can accept it*

- As per OP's request to close the question.

This `header("Content-type:image/png");` and you're using `jpg` in your `glob` brace.

- You need to use `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`